# c3p0 configuration shell command

Tags: java, shell, c3p0

I am using c3p0 connection manager, I knew that I have to put the `c3p0-config.xml` in CLASSPATH in order to read the configurtaion like `minpool`, `maxpool`,.... etc from it. Meanwhile I am looking for shell command like log4j shell command `"-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/filepath"` in order to point c3p0 to a path to `c3p0-config.xml`  in a shell command. Does anyone knows anything about this shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a System property called `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.xml` to an ordinary filepath, so

```
java -Dcom.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.xml=/path/to/xml/file
```

works. You can also specify an alternative location within your application's effective `CLASSPATH` by prepending `classloader:` to the path:

```
java -Dcom.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.xml=classloader:/META-INF/c3p0.xml
```

The default behavior is equivalent to

```
java -Dcom.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.xml=classloader:/c3p0-config.xml
```

However, when you explicitly define a path (and leave out the `classloader:` prefix) the value is treated as the path to a regular file in your file system.

Please see the documentation, "[Locating Configuration Information](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#locating_configuration_information)" and "[Overriding c3p0 defaults via c3p0-config.xml](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#c3p0-config.xml)".